# Cron configuration

Tags: drupal

How to set cron to clean drupal cache every 2 days?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set this in your server, not from Drupal.

Cron example:

minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute

```
0 * * * "MON,WED,FRI" wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

http://drupal.org/cron

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRON_expression

Comment: I know that but i don't know the command for that 

ex. 0 * * * "MON,WED,FRI" wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.mysite.com/clear_cache but i think it can't be done over url

Comment: It's not clear_cache, you call cron.php which runs all the hook_cron functions (including clearing all cache). Ask your hosting provider to input that command above. cron.php is the script that sets in motion Drupal calling all hook_cron implementations. http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_cron

Answer (score 0):

to set up a crontab entry for this to run every 2 days, only once a day at 01:00am : 
(Using step values in conjunction with ranges in crontab)

```
0 1 1-31/2 * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://yoursite.com/cron.php
```

See:

`man 5 crontab`

http://drupal.org/node/23714